# Searching database with textbox AfterUpdate

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have a data entry form and I want a specific text box to perform a search of the table to find if the data entered in the text box already exists in the related field of the table. This is the code I have currently, which returns a mismatch of datatype error on `rst.FindFirst "[SuperPNR] = & SuperPNR"`
This is confusing me...

```
Private Sub SuperPNR_AfterUpdate()
If (SuperPNR & vbNullString) = vbNullString Then Exit Sub
Dim dbs As DAO.Database
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset

Set dbs = CurrentDb
Set rst = dbs.OpenRecordset("Travel Fraud Data - Test")

rst.FindFirst "[SuperPNR] = & SuperPNR"
If rst.NoMatch Then

Else
    MsgBox "Record Already In Database!", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Do Not Save Record!"
End If
rst.Close
Set rst = Nothing
Set dbs = Nothing
```

End Sub

Comment: Solved! I literally had to change the data type in my table from Text to Number, that was it.

Comment: If you don't want to allow duplicates, why don't you just activate that field as index and then check "without duplicates" option?

Comment: @k.bratt it would probably be better to dlookup or dcount instead of using a recordset. Of course I dont understand all the moving parts, but if youre *only* checking for presence it would be wiser/safer to not open a recordset especially if oure not using good error handling. FYI ALWAYS use error handlingwhen using recordsets - hanging recordsets is SOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO annoying